# Why does android calls glDeleteTexture and glTexImage2D by itself, when imageviews with large images are invalidated

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, imageview

I experienced a strange behaviour of the Android ImageView, while testing some large images.

My first idea was to check for the maximum texture size and only use images below that. I also checked for OutOfMemory but that doesn't really matter for this problem.

It worked fine at first, but the invalidation of larger images took very long.

I tested a bit and found out, that the invalidation time increases aprupt on a certain pixel count.

For example:

A 3547x3547 pic took about 30ms to invalidate

A 3548x3548 pic took more than 1000ms !

The pixel count which causes this seems device specific. But an image with the max texture size was always slow on my test devices (Z3c, S4,S6).

The reason for that seem to be the `glTexImage2D` and `glDeleteTextures` calls which take lot of time. I used the openGL Tracer of eclipse to find out what takes that long.

A smaller image (in this case 2560x1920) is pretty fast:

[image]

But a large image (4096x4096) is slow. Take a look at the glTextImage2D Time:

[image]

I also wrote a code to reproduce the problem:

```
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ImageView imageView;
private Timer timer = new Timer();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // load the Bitmap from assets
    try {
        InputStream istr = getAssets().open("img_4096x4096.jpg");
    //  InputStream istr = getAssets().open("img_2559x1920.jpg");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(istr);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // force a draw call every 500ms
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    imageView.invalidate();
                    Log.i(TAG, "invalidate");
                }
            });
        }
    },0,500);
}
```

(the largeheap flag might help if you encounter memory problems)

Does anybody know why this is happening and if it is possible to prevent this?
An explanation whould be great.

I guess `glDeleteTextures` should not be called after drawing and this causes the `glTexImage2D` call on the next frame, but I have no idea why.